# Mapbox Issue with mapbox-gl-compare

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I there !

I use the function mapbox-gl-compare between 2 maps in 3D.

I notice that the first map (the terrain) is unstable when navigating. While the second card works well.

There is no specific error in the console.

FYI, this does not happen when the second map is a 2D style (terrain is off).

You can see it on the project: https://dev.viniglobe.com/

Have you noticed this problem? Is there a solution?

thanks in advance
best regards,Laurent

I tried with 2D map (terrain dem is off) : no issue
I tried with 3D map, without DEM hillshade : a problem is solved in the console but no result on the issue